# Proof regarding logic and negation of quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I've read about the following task, but don't know how to prove it:
Proof that $\neg(\forall  x ( V(x)\rightarrow F(x))\iff \exists x( V(x) \land \lnot F(x)) $.

Maybe we start by proving "$\Leftrightarrow$" by proving the contraposition:

$\neg\exists x (V(x) \land \lnot F(x)) \Rightarrow \forall  x ( V(x)\rightarrow F(x))$

Now we can make a contradiction by assuming:
$\exists x (V(x)\land \lnot F(x))$  but how do I move on now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *how* you are supposed to prove this (Formal proof? Using equivalences? Some other method?), but let me do one that uses the following basic equivalences:

$\neg \forall x \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \neg \varphi(x)$ (Quantifier Negation)

$\varphi \rightarrow \psi \Leftrightarrow \neg \varphi \lor \psi$ (Implication)

$\neg(\varphi \lor \psi) \Leftrightarrow \neg \varphi \land \neg \psi$ (DeMorgan)

$\neg \neg \varphi \Leftrightarrow \varphi $ (Double Negation)

OK, using these, we get:

$\neg \forall x (V(x) \rightarrow F(x)) \Leftrightarrow $ (Quantifier Negation)

$\exists x \neg (V(x) \rightarrow F(x)) \Leftrightarrow $ (Implication)

$\exists x \neg (\neg V(x) \lor F(x)) \Leftrightarrow $ (DeMorgan)

$\exists x (\neg \neg V(x) \land \neg F(x)) \Leftrightarrow $ (Double Negation)

$\exists x (V(x) \land \neg F(x)) $

Answer (score 0):

$\neg(\forall  x ( V(x)\rightarrow F(x))$ is equivalent with the following statement:

P: there exists at least one $x^*$, such that $V(x^*)$ does not imply $F(x^*).$

"$V(x^*)$ does not imply $F(x^*)$" is equivalent with "$V(x^*)$ and $F(x^*)$ both being true."

Thus P can be written as $\exists x( V(x) \land \lnot F(x)).$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to proving the biconditional using a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/). Using a proof checker makes sure that I am following the rules.

[image]

I used the following rules: change of quantifiers (CQ), universal elimination (∀E), universal introduction (∀I), De Morgan's laws (DeM), negation elimination (¬E), negation introduction (¬I), disjunctive syllogism (DS), double negative elimination (DNE), conditional introduction (→I), conditional elimination (¬E), indirect proof (IP), existential elimination (∃E) and biconditional introduction (↔I).

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/